# Remove bottom bar from TWA on Android with Firefox as sytem browser

Tags: android, firefox, progressive-web-apps

When using Firefox as a system browser, and when launching a TWA that was installed via the Play Store, there is a bottom bar displayed. It displays the host name, has a button to close the app, and a context menu. This bar is not visible when Chrome is the system browser. The bar is not visible in either Chrome or Firefox when launching a PWA that was installed from a browser.

Is it possible to hide this bottom bar? Note that in my case I have uploaded the `.well-known/assetlinks.json` file and it seems to be working fine as Chrome requires it to hide the bar.

This is using Firefox version 95.1.0.

**Firefox TWA:**
[image]

**Chrome TWA:**
[image]

Comment: After doing some more research, including installing the TWA on another phone and generally letting time pass, I realized Firefox had cached an older, invalid version of the `assetlinks.json` file. This lead to Firefox showing the bar and Chrome not showing the bar. Once the cache was cleared the bar is now gone in Firefox.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for this well-written question and the surprisingly simple explanation!

Comment: @ThomasHunterII are you sure? Mine Address Bar is still here after cache clear.

Comment: @Marco I was definitely sure when I wrote this. That said, I since realized I was being silly to use Firefox as a system browser when 99% my users would be using Chrome and would have a different experience. Now Chrome is my system browser, even though I use Firefox for everything else.

Comment: @ThomasHunterII you are right. Is due to Firefox. Thank you.